# REST API Login Pattern

Tags: design-patterns, rest

I am creating a REST api, closely following apigee suggestions, using nouns not verbs, api version baked into the url, two api paths per collection, GET POST PUT DELETE usage, etc.

I am working on the login system, but unsure of the proper REST way to login users.  I am not working on security at this point, just the login pattern or flow.  (Later we will be adding 2 step oAuth, with an HMAC, etc)

Possible Options

- A POST to something like  `https://api...com/v1/login.json`
- A PUT to something like `https://api...com/v1/users.json`
- Something I have not though of...

What is the proper REST style for logging in users?

Comment: That is the response format.    .json tells the server to respond with json, .xml tells the server to respond with xml format.  Rather that making it an optional parameter behind the ?.  http://blog.apigee.com/detail/restful_api_design_support_multiple_formats

Comment: @Oded I guess to distinct between json and xml.

Comment: Never seen content negotiation done on the URL, only in headers. On the URL it means you lose benefits of caching and more.

Comment: @ScottRoepnack then you should consider the `Accept` HTTP header.

Comment: @Oded If you used an `Accept` header, you'd also have a `Vary: Accept`, so caching wouldn't be affected. Conneg in extension has been [discussed before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/381568/rest-content-type-should-it-be-based-on-extension-or-accept-header); I'd agree with Shonzilla's answer there though.

Comment: @Oded It's pretty standard in Ruby on Rails -> .json at end of URLS means return JSON.

Comment: @Henley - no a rails dev, as you can imagine. Funny way to do content negotiation.

Comment: @Oded - i don't understand. why would you lose the benefit of caching if you specify the content type in the URL (either as a .json suffix to the query path or as a type=json query param)?  And Who is "you" in this case? Who is the person that loses caching benefits? it seems to me that the results of any query can be cached regardless what is in the query path or params.

Comment: @Cheeso - I meant you end up caching multiple representation of the data, one way or another. "You" means the server, proxies and caching proxies.

Comment: Ah, I see, thanks. Yes, you're right. The caching burden is doubled.  If memory is a constraint, this could be an issue. With 64-bit machines, huge RAM, I've found cache memory is not scarce, in most cases.

Answer (score 149, accepted):

[Principled Design of the Modern Web Architecture by Roy T. Fielding and Richard N. Taylor](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/webarch_icse2000.pdf), i.e. sequence of works from all REST terminology came from, contains definition of client-server interaction:

> All REST interactions are ***stateless***. That is, each ***request contains
>   all of the information necessary for a connector to understand the
>   request, independent of any requests that may have preceded it***.

This restriction accomplishes four functions, 1st and 3rd are important in this particular case:

- *1st*: it **removes any need for the connectors to retain application state
     between requests**, thus reducing consumption of physical resources
     and improving scalability;
- *3rd*: it allows an intermediary to view and **understand a request in isolation**,
     which may be necessary when services are dynamically rearranged;

And now lets go back to your security case. Every single request should contains all required information, and authorization/authentication is not an exception. How to achieve this? Literally send all required information over wires with every request.

One of examples how to archeive this is [**hash-based message authentication code** or **HMAC**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash-based_message_authentication_code). In practice this means adding a hash code of current message to every request. Hash code calculated by *cryptographic hash function* in combination with a *secret cryptographic key*. *Cryptographic hash function* is either predefined or part of *code-on-demand* REST conception (for example JavaScript). *Secret cryptographic key*  should be provided by server to client as resource, and client uses it to calculate hash code for every request.

There are a lot of examples of **HMAC** implementations, but I'd like you to pay attention to the following three:

- [Authenticating REST Requests for Amazon Simple Storage Service (Amazon S3)](http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/s3-developer-guide/RESTAuthentication.html)
- [Answer by Mauriceless on quiestion: "How to implement HMAC Authentication in a RESTful WCF API"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8366526/443366)
- [crypto-js: JavaScript implementations of standard and secure cryptographic algorithms](http://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/#Progressive_HMAC_Hashing)

### How it works in practice

If client knows the secret key, then it's ready to operate with resources. Otherwise he will be temporarily redirected (status code 307 Temporary Redirect) to authorize and to get secret key, and then redirected back to the original resource. In this case there is *no need to know beforehand (i.e. hardcode somewhere) what the URL to authorize the client is*, and it possible to adjust this schema with time.

Hope this will helps you to find the proper solution!

Comment: A MAC is meant to prove message authencity and protect against tampering with - it has nothing to do with user authentication

Comment: Added one of examples, how to handle user/client authentication without knowing of "_login URL_" beforehand

Comment: Here is another two nice articles with stateless auth examples for REST services:
http://blog.jdriven.com/2014/10/stateless-spring-security-part-2-stateless-authentication/
http://technicalrex.com/2015/02/20/stateless-authentication-with-spring-security-and-jwt/

Answer (score 41):

**TL;DR** Login for each request is not a required component to implement API security, authentication is.

It is hard to answer your question about login without talking about security in general. With some authentication schemes, there's no traditional login.

REST does not dictate any security rules, but the most common implementation in practice is OAuth with 3-way authentication (as you've mentioned in your question). There is no log-in per se, at least not with each API request. With 3-way auth, you just use tokens.

1. User approves API client and grants permission to make requests in the form of a long-lived token
2. Api client obtains a short-lived token by using the long-lived one.
3. Api client sends the short-lived token with each request.

This scheme gives the user the option to revoke access at any time. Practially all publicly available RESTful APIs I've seen use OAuth to implement this.

I just don't think you should frame your problem (and question) in terms of login, but rather think about securing the API in general.

For further info on authentication of REST APIs in general, you can look at the following resources:

- http://www.infoq.com/news/2010/01/rest-api-authentication-schemes
- [REST API Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7999295/rest-api-authentication)
- [RESTful API Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7606559/restful-api-authentication)

Comment: Yes, OAuth! Very straightforward answer, should be the accepted answer, imho.

Answer (score 26):

A big part of the REST philosophy is to exploit as many standard features of the HTTP protocol as possible when designing your API.  Applying that philosophy to authentication, client and server would utilize standard HTTP authentication features in the API.

Login screens are great for human user use cases: visit a login screen, provide user/password, set a cookie, client provides that cookie in all future requests.  Humans using web browsers can't be expected to provide a user id and password with each individual HTTP request.

But for a REST API, a login screen and session cookies are not strictly necessary, since each request can include credentials without impacting a human user; and if the client does not cooperate at any time, a `401` "unauthorized" response can be given.  [RFC 2617](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2617) describes authentication support in HTTP.

TLS (HTTPS) would also be an option, and would allow authentication of the client to the server (and vice versa) in every request by verifying the public key of the other party.  Additionally this secures the channel for a bonus.  Of course, a keypair exchange prior to communication is necessary to do this.  (Note, this is specifically about identifying/authenticating the user with TLS.  Securing the channel by using TLS / Diffie-Hellman is always a good idea, even if you don't identify the user by its public key.)

An example: suppose that an OAuth token is your complete login credentials.  Once the client has the OAuth token, it could be provided as the user id in standard HTTP authentication with each request.  The server could verify the token on first use and cache the result of the check with a time-to-live that gets renewed with each request.  Any request requiring authentication returns `401` if not provided.

Comment: "since each request can include credentials without impacting a human user"

3-way authentication and OAuth were invented because the thing in the quotes is bad. If you supply credentials with each request without a mechanism on the server to revoke them, that would be unsecure if used w/o SSL.

Comment: Whenever there is a concept of users, something has to get passed from client to server to identify which user.  An OAuth token can certainly serve as the "credentials" here, instead of an actual user/password combination.  Securing the channel with TLS is certainly always a good thing, but that's almost beside the point.  Even if you use a cookie, some sort of token still gets sent to the server with every request, just with a cookie header instead of an authentication header.

Comment: And if you're not using TLS or OAuth for whatever reason, is sending a user/password every time really worse than sending it only once?  If the attacker can obtain the user/password, the attacker can likely also obtain the session cookie.

Comment: The difference between a cookie and an authentication header being credentials is that cookies are always associated to a particular domain. This means that when the API receives a cookie, it knows where it came from (was written by the same domain earlier). With a header, you never know and you have to implement specific checks for this. In general I agree, they are both credentials, but I think that passing credentials is not login. Login is the active action of opening the door. In the case of 3-way auth, only the first approval of the client would be login.