# How to manage login flow in ios app

Tags: php, ios, iphone, authentication, access-token

I'm developing an iOS app which needs a registration through php server and MySQL and works perfectly, but I have a bigger problem.

How can I manage login flow?

Do you have any link from which I can get the correct way to manage it?

Should I use access token in some way? If yes, how can I do it?

Comment: what it works perfectly?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13916620/rest-api-login-pattern

Comment: How should this help me?

Comment: in your question you ask for information about how to manage the login flow... well the most common pattern is to have an api that the client (your app) consume. So the link will help you if you read it!

Comment: I'm reading it..hoping that it will help me. ;) anyway I should search for rest API, correct??

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40279/discussion-between-bellots-and-elio-d)