# What is the accepted practice for URL login in API REST?

Tags: rest, url, api-design

If I have: users, and I need to log in with API rest. What's the best way to do it?

1. `/users/id/password`
2. `/users?id=id&password=pass`

If I use the second option, I will need to validate if there are get parameters. If not, It will return all results.

This is not the answer I want now:
[REST API Login Pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13916620/rest-api-login-pattern)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The link you added is valid, REST APIs are stateless, so they can't login in the traditional way, you MUST store the client session on the client side. If you use HTTPs you won't need login. If you don't, then your API won't be secure, so using password won't have any protection. I think that's all.

If you want to both stay stateless and send tokens, then you have to sign for example the user id on the server. So by the next request you can send both the user id and the signature instead of the email and password. This way the server will know that you have been logged in earlier to the account the user id belongs to. I don't recommend you to use the URI for sending sensitive data. It is better to use the request body with POST. The URI structure depends on your taste, I would use something like this:

```
POST /users/1/tokens/ {email: "..", password: ".."}
201 {id: 1, expires: "..", signature: ".."}
```

Be aware that you have to send every variables you signed, so, the id, the expiration time (added by the server), probably the ip address, a random number, etc... You MUST not store anything on the server (including the token), otherwise the communication will be stateful.

I am not a security expert, but I think this solution does not make sense in most of the cases, so you need to justify somehow, why your API needs it. It is used for example for signing each request coming from 3rd party clients. If you cannot justify it, I recommend you to use the default approach, which is using HTTPS, logging in on the client side and sending HTTP Authorization header with email and password by every request.

Comment: I think this is a misunderstanding. Tokens or whatever are just as valid objects to store server-side, just like the user object itself (especially to compare for authentication or whatever)

Answer (score 4):

I would use a POST method with the login / password provided within the payload:

```
POST /login
Content-Type: application/json

{ username: 'some username', password: 'some password' }
```

In addition, the following link could give you some hints about authentication within RESTful services:

- Implementing authentication with tokens for RESTful applications - https://templth.wordpress.com/2015/01/05/implementing-authentication-with-tokens-for-restful-applications/

Hope it helps you,
Thierry